# How to cite a paper when I don't know where was published?

Tags: citations

I have collected some papers regarding the subject of my M.A. thesis,  but I have some articles that I couldn't find where they were published.   The point is when I Google the title of the article, Google shows me that the article has been cited more than 60 times, but I can't find where and in what journal. How can I find the journal in which these articles were published?

Comment: I don't understand how you can use a system that tells you how many times an article was cited without telling you where it was initially published.

Comment: Could you provide an example of such an article that Google Scholar has 60+ citations for with no clues for where it was published?

Comment: If you have a copy of the paper, then the info you need should be printed on it somewhere. If you don't have a copy of the paper, you shouldn't be trying to cite it. If you are trying to find this info so that you can find a copy for yourself to read, @aeismail's answer is the right one.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes the route that seems most tedious can end up being the most efficient. I would try looking at some of those 60+ references. Any work that's been cited so many times will have to have the source listed in the bibliography sections of those references.

Answer (score 1):

Google Scholar typically offers "Cite" button that will give you its best bibliographic information available on the citation.  That will usually give you everything you need.  If not, follow the links in Scholar to where it found the article, and there will usually be bibliographic information.  And you can also do as @aeismail suggests and look at how others have cited it.

For some particularly odd or obscure articles, however, you may still be unable to find an appropriate set of journal/conference information.  For example, technical manuals often have no official publication, but just an online reference site that is being maintained.  Another example is the [Carlson Curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlson_Curve) is widely referenced but has no official publication beyond a series of blog posts.  Still, there is always a correct way to cite: follow the principle of giving the most complete and persistent data that will allow others to find the same information that you found.